# how to avoid refreshing of screen while changing flash mode in android X

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm trying to change the flash mode like below

```
when {
    ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_AUTO == imageCapture!!.flashMode -> {
        imageCaptureFlashMode = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_ON
        idFlashControl.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_on)
        startCamera()
    }
...
...
```

in startCamera() I'm binding the use cases like below

```
cameraProvider?.unbindAll()
val cameraX = cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(
            this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture
        )
```

unbinding is recreating the surface. So, when I change the flash mode the screen goes black and come back to life like a new activity is created.

How to avoid this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to unbind/rebind the use cases when changing the image capture use case's flash mode. When you set the flash mode to `FLASH_MODE_ON`, the subsequent capture requests will use the flash (assuming the device supports flash).

```
// Assuming the image capture has already been bound
imageCapture.flashMode = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_ON

// Assuming the flash unit is available, this capture request will use the flash
imageCapture.takePicture(...)
```

Comment: I have similar issue (surface recreated) but with focus mode. To set focus to infinity I use `Camera2Interop.Extender` and call setCaptureRequestOption on previewBuilder. If later I want to use auto-focus again, I need to recreate previewBuilder and rebind use case which causes surface to blink. Is there a solution for my use case?